# Javascript endless loop without for

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

This function is running continuously without initiating a loop.

The setTimeout is to allow the refreshTags function to run.

I'm sure it's not the best-written script - I'm no guru - but any ideas on why this script is running in an endless loop?

```
function addTag() 
{
console.log('running'); 
refreshTags(); 
var t = document.getElementById('existingTags').textContent.match(/tag1/); 
var u = 'tag1'; 
if (t == u) {alert('This ticket has already been resolved by our team.')}; 
if (t != u) 
    {
    refreshTags();
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        document.getElementById('tagToAdd').value = 'tag1';
        document.getElementById('tagSubmit').click(); 
        alert('Ticket resolved!'); 
    }, 2000)
}; 
}
```

Edit: code calling addTag below.

```
var resolveButton = document.createElement("a");
resolveButton.href = '#';
resolveButton.innerHTML = '<span>Resolve</span>';
resolveButton.setAttribute("onClick", "addTag()");
resolveButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
resolveButton.setAttribute("class", "button1");

var cha = document.getElementById('chatter_view');
cha.parentNode.insertBefore(resolveButton, cha);
```

Comment: may be because of this line that simulates a click document.getElementById('tagSubmit').click();

Comment: Again, please forgive my ignorance - why would this cause an issue?

Comment: What does the refreshTags function look like? Does it call addTag by chance?

Comment: was just a guess. need to see more of your code. in particular when you run the add tag function.

Comment: He's not wrong, it could be a problem if the tagSubmit element has an onclick handler which in turn calls addTag again.

Comment: tagSubmit and refreshTags don't call addTag. Sorry I can't post this code - the above is a Greasemonkey script, tagSubmit and refreshTags are scripts local to the webpage. I'll post the code calling the addTag function.

Comment: Okay, maybe this is the problem?

resolveButton.setAttribute("onClick", "addTag()");
document.getElementById('tagSubmit').click();

Comment: not really, those don't have same ids, so they are different. what happens when tagSubmit element is clicked? and do u run addTag on page load?

Comment: Okay - figured out the problem. The local tagSubmit function called another local function ALSO named addTag. So I was calling the local addTag function as well as the addTag function in my script. Renamed the function in my script to addTag1 and seems to have resolved the issue.

Thanks everyone for guiding me in the right direction!

Comment: Why would you use `setAttribute("onClick", "blah()")` when you could just do `.onclick = blah;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to answer why this particular piece of code has an infinite loop, I'll attempt to answer the bigger question "How do you prevent and debug infinite loops?".

One of the best defenses I've found is to structure your code so control is always flowing in one direction.  You have a number of different layers here:

- the onclick event handler is calling into addTag()
- addTag() is calling refreshTags()
- addTag() is calling a setTimeout, which later triggers a click on the DOM.

A simple fix to keep your code flowing in one direction is to create dedicated event handlers, e.g. `resolveButtonOnclick() { addTag() }`.  resolveButtonOnclick is only ever called from the resolveButton's onclick handler.  This makes it much easier to audit your code. You've already put a `console.log('running')` at the top of your addTag() function.  Now, if you put a console.log() in resolveButtonOnclick() you'll know right away if the onclick handler is included in your infinite loop.

We can't see your code, but if refreshTags() calls addTag() you would have a circular control flow -- these aren't always bad, but you need to be extra careful that they terminate at some point.

The biggest circular control flow you may have is that addTag() is calling back into the DOM with the .click() method.  It would be better, faster and cleaner to submit the form directly from the Javascript or use an XHR.

To debug this loop, you are one the right track with the console.log()s.  Add more of them (e.g. every place you call addTag()) and figure out where it is being called from.  The other thing you could try is using Chrome's DevTools: add a 'debugger;' call to the top of addTag() and examine the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer, James. I was able to resolve my issue earlier - see my comment to my original question - there were two addTag functions, one in the script, one (that I didn't write) in the page.

I have a lot to learn, I am not a developer, which I'm sure is evident, and I do a lot of my learning from code written by actual developers at my company - so maybe I've been picking up some bad habits! :)

But while this is not my day job it's a lot of fun to learn new ways like this to think about structuring code. Thanks again for sharing, I'll try to implement this method.